# Trying to access data in Elasticsearch indecies

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5

There is an index created on Elastic Kibnana and trying to access and update.
I am not sure if I understood correctly.

For example, let's say I have my own domain called "123.45.67.89:6000."

**In Python, this is what I have**

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch("http://123.45.67.89:6000")
es.indices.get_alias()
```

The following code fails to retrieve with 400 error message.

> elasticsearch.exceptions.NotFoundError: NotFoundError(404, 'Not
> Found', 'Not Found')

**Question:** How can I access or fetch data from "operationratefinal"?

If I were to use "get_alias," I was expecting result from **"operationratefinal."**

> Below is what I have from Kibana,

[image]

Comment: Can you check in Kibana's configuration, what is the underlying ES host:port that it connects to? That's the URL you need to use in your Python code, not Kibana's browser address.

Comment: Default port for elasticsearch is `9200` and also you want perform search on `operationratefinal` index not a `get_alias` which is different thing.

Comment: @Val, Thank you! I was able to connect after modifying the config file. I should have paid attention to installation instruction!

Comment: @Rohlik, how should I search "operationratefinal"?

Comment: @user14581248 You can get some inspiration here https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.9.1/#example-usage

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, I solved it using port 9200.
[Here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-are-ports-9200-and-9300-used-for/238578) are Elastic Search docs about it.